# I cannot get bootstrap-sass to work in development environment but can get it to work in production and test env rails 6.1.3.1

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bootstrap-sass, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am able to launch my application in two environments using AWS EB and one Cloud9 IDE. I have no errors that I can see. My development environment seems to be missing bootstrap-sass assets. I am getting my formatting but not bootstrap-sass css styles/classes/ids. I am using a blank Rails application and have built few static pages to work on formatting.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.3'

gem 'rails',                      '6.1.3.1'
gem 'puma',                       '5.2.2'
gem 'mysql2',                     '~> 0.5.3'
gem 'sass-rails',                 '6.0.0'
gem 'webpacker',                  '~> 5.2.1', '>= 5.2'
gem 'turbolinks',                 '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'jbuilder',                   '~> 2.10.0'
gem 'bootsnap',                   '~> 1.7.2', require: false
gem 'bcrypt',                     '~> 3.1.13'
gem 'faker',                      '~> 2.11.0'
gem 'will_paginate',              '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate',    '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',             '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'image_processing',           '1.9.3'
gem 'mini_magick',                '4.9.5'
gem 'active_storage_validations', '0.8.9'


group :development do
  gem 'web-console',        '4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '2.3.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',                 '~> 3.35.3'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver',       '~> 3.142.7'
  gem 'webdrivers',               '~> 4.6.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '~> 1.0.5'
  gem 'minitest',                 '~> 5.14.4'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '~> 1.3.8'
  gem 'guard',                    '~> 2.16.2'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '~> 2.4.6'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'listen',  '~> 3.4.1'
  gem 'spring',  '~> 2.1.1'
  gem 'byebug',  '~> 11.1.3', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end
```

Here are my versions:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails -v
Rails 6.1.3.1
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 2.2.15
$ yarn -v
1.22.10
```

Both of my production and development environment variables have RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION set to false

I am using a vanilla rails application. Routes work, controllers work.

EB engine log:

```
2021/05/11 22:56:28.732031 [INFO] Starting...
2021/05/11 22:56:28.732076 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2021/05/11 22:56:28.732097 [INFO] reading event message file
2021/05/11 22:56:28.732189 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2021/05/11 22:56:28.732240 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2021/05/11 22:56:28.805972 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:535214081593:stack/awseb-e-h5i2z9cxvn-stack/9e492980-ae00-11eb-8feb-02989f3e79db -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-west-2
2021/05/11 22:56:29.206306 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:535214081593:stack/awseb-e-h5i2z9cxvn-stack/9e492980-ae00-11eb-8feb-02989f3e79db -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-west-2
2021/05/11 22:56:29.531954 [INFO] checking whether command app-deploy is applicable to this instance...
2021/05/11 22:56:29.531965 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2021/05/11 22:56:29.531968 [INFO] Engine command: (app-deploy)

2021/05/11 22:56:29.531972 [INFO] Downloading EB Application...
2021/05/11 22:56:29.531974 [INFO] Region: us-west-2
2021/05/11 22:56:29.531976 [INFO] envID: e-h5i2z9cxvn
2021/05/11 22:56:29.531979 [INFO] envBucket: elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-535214081593
2021/05/11 22:56:29.531981 [INFO] Using manifest file name from command request
2021/05/11 22:56:29.531987 [INFO] Manifest name is : manifest_1620773786334
2021/05/11 22:56:29.531989 [INFO] Download app version manifest
2021/05/11 22:56:29.532091 [INFO] Downloading: bucket: elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-535214081593, object: /resources/environments/e-h5i2z9cxvn/_runtime/versions/manifest_1620773786334
2021/05/11 22:56:29.579146 [INFO] Download successful161bytes downloaded
2021/05/11 22:56:29.579286 [INFO] Trying to read and parse version manifest...
2021/05/11 22:56:29.579368 [INFO] Downloading: bucket: elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-535214081593, object: /resources/environments/e-h5i2z9cxvn/_runtime/_versions/AW Factory Application/code-pipeline-1620773780662-d4a18b7995ea68d0fbf463560b41798f05507098
2021/05/11 22:56:29.598064 [INFO] Download successful167376bytes downloaded
2021/05/11 22:56:29.598277 [INFO] Executing instruction: ElectLeader
2021/05/11 22:56:29.598284 [INFO] Running leader election for instance i-0ae696955516df1e3...
2021/05/11 22:56:29.598288 [INFO] Calling the cfn-elect-cmd-leader to elect the command leader.
2021/05/11 22:56:29.598380 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-elect-cmd-leader --stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:535214081593:stack/awseb-e-h5i2z9cxvn-stack/9e492980-ae00-11eb-8feb-02989f3e79db --command-name ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --invocation-id d6342566-20ee-4d6f-b68b-efc8a58a24ba --listener-id i-0ae696955516df1e3 --region us-west-2
2021/05/11 22:56:29.860975 [INFO] Instance is Leader.
2021/05/11 22:56:29.861014 [INFO] Executing instruction: stopSqsd
2021/05/11 22:56:29.861019 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip stop sqsd daemon ...
2021/05/11 22:56:29.861022 [INFO] Executing instruction: PreBuildEbExtension
2021/05/11 22:56:29.861025 [INFO] Starting executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild.
2021/05/11 22:56:29.861037 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:535214081593:stack/awseb-e-h5i2z9cxvn-stack/9e492980-ae00-11eb-8feb-02989f3e79db -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-west-2 --configsets Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021/05/11 22:56:33.349134 [INFO] Finished executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild.

2021/05/11 22:56:33.349160 [INFO] Executing instruction: StageApplication
2021/05/11 22:56:33.349355 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2021/05/11 22:56:33.349374 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2021/05/11 22:56:33.381495 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2021/05/11 22:56:33.384590 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
2021/05/11 22:56:33.384626 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/prebuild/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2021/05/11 22:56:33.384631 [INFO] Executing instruction: stage ruby application
2021/05/11 22:56:33.384636 [INFO] stage ruby application ....
2021/05/11 22:56:33.384684 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c bundle config set --local deployment true
2021/05/11 22:56:33.650304 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c bundle install
2021/05/11 22:59:22.474121 [INFO] Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching rake 13.0.3
Installing rake 13.0.3
Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Fetching minitest 5.14.4
Installing minitest 5.14.4
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Fetching zeitwerk 2.4.2
Installing zeitwerk 2.4.2
Fetching builder 3.2.4
Fetching erubi 1.10.0
Installing builder 3.2.4
Installing erubi 1.10.0
Fetching racc 1.5.2
Fetching crass 1.0.6
Installing crass 1.0.6
Installing racc 1.5.2 with native extensions
Fetching rack 2.2.3
Installing rack 2.2.3
Fetching nio4r 2.5.7
Installing nio4r 2.5.7 with native extensions
Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Fetching marcel 1.0.1
Installing marcel 1.0.1
Fetching mini_mime 1.0.3
Installing mini_mime 1.0.3
Using bundler 2.2.15
Fetching method_source 1.0.0
Installing method_source 1.0.0
Fetching thor 1.1.0
Installing thor 1.1.0
Fetching execjs 2.7.0
Installing execjs 2.7.0
Fetching bcrypt 3.1.16
Installing bcrypt 3.1.16 with native extensions
Fetching bindex 0.8.1
Installing bindex 0.8.1 with native extensions
Fetching msgpack 1.4.2
Installing msgpack 1.4.2 with native extensions
Fetching ffi 1.15.0
Installing ffi 1.15.0 with native extensions
Fetching will_paginate 3.3.0
Installing will_paginate 3.3.0
Fetching byebug 11.1.3
Installing byebug 11.1.3 with native extensions
Fetching mini_magick 4.9.5
Installing mini_magick 4.9.5
Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.4
Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.4
Fetching mysql2 0.5.3
Installing mysql2 0.5.3 with native extensions
Fetching tilt 2.0.10
Installing tilt 2.0.10
Fetching semantic_range 3.0.0
Installing semantic_range 3.0.0
Fetching spring 2.1.1
Installing spring 2.1.1
Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Fetching i18n 1.8.10
Installing i18n 1.8.10
Fetching tzinfo 2.0.4
Installing tzinfo 2.0.4
Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
Installing rack-test 1.1.0
Fetching sprockets 4.0.2
Installing sprockets 4.0.2
Fetching rack-mini-profiler 2.3.1
Installing rack-mini-profiler 2.3.1
Fetching rack-proxy 0.6.5
Installing rack-proxy 0.6.5
Fetching nokogiri 1.11.3 (x86_64-linux)
Installing nokogiri 1.11.3 (x86_64-linux)
Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.3
Installing websocket-driver 0.7.3 with native extensions
Fetching mail 2.7.1
Installing mail 2.7.1
Fetching autoprefixer-rails 10.2.4.0
Installing autoprefixer-rails 10.2.4.0
Fetching puma 5.2.2
Installing puma 5.2.2 with native extensions
Fetching bootsnap 1.7.5
Installing bootsnap 1.7.5 with native extensions
Fetching bootstrap-will_paginate 1.0.0
Installing bootstrap-will_paginate 1.0.0
Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1
Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
Fetching faker 2.11.0
Installing faker 2.11.0
Fetching activesupport 6.1.3.1
Installing activesupport 6.1.3.1
Fetching loofah 2.9.1
Installing loofah 2.9.1
Fetching sassc 2.4.0
Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions
Fetching ruby-vips 2.1.2
Installing ruby-vips 2.1.2
Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Fetching globalid 0.4.2
Installing globalid 0.4.2
Fetching activemodel 6.1.3.1
Installing activemodel 6.1.3.1
Fetching jbuilder 2.10.2
Installing jbuilder 2.10.2
Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Fetching image_processing 1.9.3
Installing image_processing 1.9.3
Fetching listen 3.4.1
Installing listen 3.4.1
Fetching activejob 6.1.3.1
Installing activejob 6.1.3.1
Fetching activerecord 6.1.3.1
Installing activerecord 6.1.3.1
Fetching actionview 6.1.3.1
Installing actionview 6.1.3.1
Fetching actionpack 6.1.3.1
Installing actionpack 6.1.3.1
Fetching actioncable 6.1.3.1
Installing actioncable 6.1.3.1
Fetching activestorage 6.1.3.1
Installing activestorage 6.1.3.1
Fetching actionmailer 6.1.3.1
Installing actionmailer 6.1.3.1
Fetching railties 6.1.3.1
Installing railties 6.1.3.1
Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Fetching actionmailbox 6.1.3.1
Installing actionmailbox 6.1.3.1
Fetching actiontext 6.1.3.1
Installing actiontext 6.1.3.1
Fetching web-console 4.1.0
Installing web-console 4.1.0
Fetching webpacker 5.2.2
Installing webpacker 5.2.2
Fetching rails 6.1.3.1
Installing rails 6.1.3.1
Fetching active_storage_validations 0.8.9
Installing active_storage_validations 0.8.9
Fetching bootstrap-sass 3.4.1
Fetching sassc-rails 2.1.2
Installing sassc-rails 2.1.2
Installing bootstrap-sass 3.4.1
Fetching sass-rails 6.0.0
Installing sass-rails 6.0.0
Bundle complete! 29 Gemfile dependencies, 75 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups test and production were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`

2021/05/11 22:59:22.474164 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c rbenv rehash
2021/05/11 22:59:22.499190 [INFO] encountered a Gemfile.lock, setting proper permissions to user webapp
2021/05/11 22:59:22.499312 [INFO] Executing instruction: check default web server
2021/05/11 22:59:22.503526 [INFO] Executing instruction: check procfile
2021/05/11 22:59:22.503545 [INFO] creating default Procfile...
2021/05/11 22:59:22.503582 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure X-Ray
2021/05/11 22:59:22.503586 [INFO] X-Ray is not enabled.
2021/05/11 22:59:22.503588 [INFO] Executing instruction: Configure proxy Nginx
2021/05/11 22:59:22.503591 [INFO] configuring proxy...
2021/05/11 22:59:22.503849 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/nginx/webapp.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/webapp.conf
2021/05/11 22:59:22.505736 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/nginx/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-ruby-upstream.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-ruby-upstream.conf
2021/05/11 22:59:22.512827 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure healthd specific proxy conf
2021/05/11 22:59:22.514349 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
2021/05/11 22:59:22.518590 [WARN] Warning: process healthd is already registered...
Deregistering the process ...
2021/05/11 22:59:22.518611 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
2021/05/11 22:59:22.522307 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active healthd.service
2021/05/11 22:59:22.525438 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
2021/05/11 22:59:22.529252 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop healthd.service
2021/05/11 22:59:22.546698 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl disable healthd.service
2021/05/11 22:59:22.623484 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2021/05/11 22:59:22.686937 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2021/05/11 22:59:22.694064 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2021/05/11 22:59:22.759063 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2021/05/11 22:59:22.763812 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-enabled aws-eb.target
2021/05/11 22:59:22.767197 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable aws-eb.target
2021/05/11 22:59:22.830574 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start aws-eb.target
2021/05/11 22:59:22.834350 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable healthd.service
2021/05/11 22:59:22.902900 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
2021/05/11 22:59:22.908588 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active healthd.service
2021/05/11 22:59:22.911726 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start healthd.service
2021/05/11 22:59:22.934207 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_logformat.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/healthd_logformat.conf
2021/05/11 22:59:22.935962 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_nginx.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/healthd.conf
2021/05/11 22:59:22.937546 [INFO] Executing instruction: rake tasks
2021/05/11 22:59:22.937574 [INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb assets:precompile
2021/05/11 22:59:25.469323 [INFO] Found assets:precompile task in Rakefile
2021/05/11 22:59:25.469363 [INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec rake assets:precompile
2021/05/11 22:59:38.900826 [INFO] yarn install v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 4.52s.
Compiling...
Compiled all packs in /var/app/staging/public/packs
Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.

Hash: 0613a9b3364c08fc0d50
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 4286ms
Built at: 05/11/2021 10:59:38 PM
                                        Asset       Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
       js/application-12f04455053704825e8e.js   69.3 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]  application
    js/application-12f04455053704825e8e.js.br   15.4 KiB          [emitted]              
    js/application-12f04455053704825e8e.js.gz   17.8 KiB          [emitted]              
   js/application-12f04455053704825e8e.js.map    205 KiB       0  [emitted] [dev]        application
js/application-12f04455053704825e8e.js.map.br   43.8 KiB          [emitted]              
js/application-12f04455053704825e8e.js.map.gz   50.9 KiB          [emitted]              
                                manifest.json  364 bytes          [emitted]              
                             manifest.json.br  132 bytes          [emitted]              
                             manifest.json.gz  142 bytes          [emitted]              
Entrypoint application = js/application-12f04455053704825e8e.js js/application-12f04455053704825e8e.js.map
[0] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 552 bytes {0} [built]
[4] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 480 bytes {0} [built]
[5] ./app/javascript/channels/index.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
[6] ./app/javascript/channels sync _channel\.js$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
    + 3 hidden modules


2021/05/11 22:59:38.900873 [INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb db:migrate
2021/05/11 22:59:39.649650 [INFO] Found db:migrate task in Rakefile
2021/05/11 22:59:39.649694 [INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec rake db:migrate
2021/05/11 22:59:40.860089 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure log streaming
2021/05/11 22:59:40.860118 [INFO] start to get cloudwatch log client
2021/05/11 22:59:40.860248 [INFO] start to config log streaming
2021/05/11 22:59:40.860258 [INFO] start to configure log streaming config file
2021/05/11 22:59:40.860529 [INFO] start to create cloudwatch log stream
2021/05/11 22:59:40.860535 [INFO] start to create log streaming
2021/05/11 22:59:40.883301 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/AWOPSDevelopmentEnvironment/var/log/eb-engine.log already exists. No need to create it.
2021/05/11 22:59:40.913103 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/AWOPSDevelopmentEnvironment/var/log/eb-hooks.log already exists. No need to create it.
2021/05/11 22:59:40.946041 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/AWOPSDevelopmentEnvironment/var/log/nginx/access.log already exists. No need to create it.
2021/05/11 22:59:40.985928 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/AWOPSDevelopmentEnvironment/var/log/nginx/error.log already exists. No need to create it.
2021/05/11 22:59:41.010658 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/AWOPSDevelopmentEnvironment/var/log/web.stdout.log already exists. No need to create it.
2021/05/11 22:59:41.049965 [WARN] Log stream for log group /aws/elasticbeanstalk/AWOPSDevelopmentEnvironment/var/log/puma/puma.log already exists. No need to create it.
2021/05/11 22:59:41.049986 [INFO] start to fetch config
2021/05/11 22:59:41.049998 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/beanstalk.json -s
2021/05/11 22:59:41.414614 [INFO] ****** processing amazon-cloudwatch-agent ******
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-downloader --output-dir /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d --download-source file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/beanstalk.json --mode ec2 --config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml --multi-config default
Successfully fetched the config and saved in /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/file_beanstalk.json.tmp
Start configuration validation...
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-translator --input /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json --input-dir /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d --output /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml --mode ec2 --config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml --multi-config default
Valid Json input schema.
I! Detecting run_as_user...
No csm configuration found.
No metric configuration found.
Configuration validation first phase succeeded
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent -schematest -config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml
Configuration validation second phase succeeded
Configuration validation succeeded

2021/05/11 22:59:41.414645 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetToggleForceRotate
2021/05/11 22:59:41.414649 [INFO] Checking if logs need forced rotation
2021/05/11 22:59:41.414666 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:535214081593:stack/awseb-e-h5i2z9cxvn-stack/9e492980-ae00-11eb-8feb-02989f3e79db -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-west-2
2021/05/11 22:59:41.693055 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:535214081593:stack/awseb-e-h5i2z9cxvn-stack/9e492980-ae00-11eb-8feb-02989f3e79db -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-west-2
2021/05/11 22:59:41.954294 [INFO] Generating rsyslog config from Procfile
2021/05/11 22:59:41.955805 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl restart rsyslog.service
2021/05/11 22:59:41.973105 [INFO] Executing instruction: PostBuildEbExtension
2021/05/11 22:59:41.973133 [INFO] Starting executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild.
........
```

Comment: My nodejs version. I had to add installation instructions to add nodejs to the EB environment. Yum was installing 6.17.X something. I have 14.16.1 installed.

Comment: hi, was there an error returned

Comment: not that I can find. I am looking for the error myself. It is as if the css files are absent. I will ssh into the instance and will look at the logs in /var/logs and deployed app in /var/app/current. I can compare the production vs development environments. The app is the same. There is configuration differences, but all of these differences are from the original vanilla app setup.

Comment: My development and production instances and EB environment is almost identical except for the env variables. There are differences in the webpacker setup and rails settings. I cant figure out why the app works in the production but not in the development environment.

Comment: I will start debugging the framework tomorrow.